# text String to an int

Tags: java, string

Hi I am new to java and looking for advice.

I want to take the result of the method `Country_name` and covert this result to an int and pass it in to the method `calc_pop_pre_sq_ft`.

From the example below, I enter France which is associated with a String result of "66 Million".

How would I take the String "`66 Million"` and change this to the int `66` and pass this in to my method?

At the moment I am passing `66` manually

```
calc1.calc_pop_pre_sq_ft(66,2);
```

I get the output

```
Country Population is 66million
Population is 33 Million people per square mile
```

Do I need to setup an array with String and int values associated with each String and then pass location of a country in that Array in to the method?

```
public class StringTest {

String Country_Name;

String Country_Name(String eName){

    if (eName.equals ("UK")) {
        Country_Name = "60";
    } else if (eName.equals ("USA")) {
        Country_Name = "318";
    } else if (eName.equals ("Japan")) {
        Country_Name = "127";
    } else if (eName.equals ("France")) {
        Country_Name = "66";
    } 
    else {
        Country_Name = "no country selected";
    }
        return Country_Name;
}       

public int calc_pop_pre_sq_ft( int enter_Popu_in_Million, int enterSqumiles) {

    int a_popu_per_sq_m = enter_Popu_in_Million / enterSqumiles;        
    return a_popu_per_sq_m;
    }   

public static void main(String[] args) {    

StringTest calc1 = new StringTest();

int aSquaremiles = calc1.calc_pop_pre_sq_ft(66,2);
String aCountry = calc1.Country_Name("France"); 

System.out.println("Country Population is " + aCountry + " million");
System.out.println("Population is " + aSquaremiles + " Million people per square mile");
}
}
```

Comment: Since you are only returning numbers in a string, why can't `Country_Name` just return an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, each basic data type has its own parser method implemented in his corresponding class. If you want to obtain an `int` out of your `String` returning method, you could do something like:

`String aCountry = calc1.Country_Name("France"); 
int country_number = Integer.parseInt(aCountry);`

Note that aCountry will keep having a `String` stored, but now you will have this `String` as an `int` stored in country_number.

Moreover, you can actually return an int from your Country_name method. It'd be like:

> int Country_Name(String eName){
>
> ```
> int Country_Name;
>
> if (eName.equals ("UK")) {
>     Country_Name = 60;
> } else if (eName.equals ("USA")) {
>     Country_Name = 318;
> } else if (eName.equals ("Japan")) {
>     Country_Name = 127;
> } else if (eName.equals ("France")) {
>     Country_Name = 66;
> } 
> else {
>     Country_Name = -1;
> }
>     return Country_Name;
> ```
>
> }

Then, when you call the method, you should control that it's not returning -1, since this would mean that no countries were selected. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To convert a String to an int you can do the following:

```
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(myStringNumber);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

       log.error("This is not a number.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I think this program will help you a lot.

```
public class StringTest {

String Country_Name;

String Country_Name(String eName){

if (eName.equals ("UK")) {
    Country_Name = "60";
} else if (eName.equals ("USA")) {
    Country_Name = "318";
} else if (eName.equals ("Japan")) {
    Country_Name = "127";
} else if (eName.equals ("France")) {
    Country_Name = "66";
}
else {
    Country_Name = "-1";
}
    return Country_Name;

}


public int calc_pop_pre_sq_ft( int enter_Popu_in_Million, int enterSqumiles) {

int a_popu_per_sq_m = enter_Popu_in_Million / enterSqumiles;
return a_popu_per_sq_m;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

StringTest calc1 = new StringTest();

int aCountry = Integer.parseInt(calc1.Country_Name("France"));
if (aCountry != -1){
    int aSquaremiles = calc1.calc_pop_pre_sq_ft(aCountry,2);

    System.out.println("Country Population is " + aCountry + " million");
    System.out.println("Population is " + aSquaremiles + " Million people per square mile");
}

else{
    System.out.println("No country selected.");
}
}
```